# Building a timelapse with ffmpy

Tags: python, beginner, image, video

As a 'trying to learn Python' project, I am using ffmpy to stitch together a timelapse from a series of still images. I'd like the script to output a couple of formats for web use.

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import ffmpy
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()
ydr = now.strftime('%Y')
mdr = now.strftime('%m')
ddr = now.strftime('%d')

ipath = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + '/images/' + ydr + '/' + mdr + '/*/*.jpg'
opath1 = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + '/videos/' + ydr + mdr + '.mp4'
opath2 = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + '/videos/' + ydr + mdr + '.webm'

ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
    inputs={ipath: '-loglevel info -pattern_type glob -framerate 18 '},
    outputs={opath1: '-c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1280:-1,hqdn3d=luma_spatial=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p'}
)
ff.run()

ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
    inputs={ipath: '-loglevel info -pattern_type glob -framerate 18 '},
    outputs={opath2: '-c:v libvpx -vf "scale=1280:-1,hqdn3d=luma_spatial=1" -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis'}
)
ff.run()
```

It works, but it's kinda ugly and I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient and 'Pythonic' way of doing this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `path.join()` instead of manually concatenating file paths

  This will make sure that it will work on different OS's, windows uses `\` backslashes for instance
- No need to convert with `strftime`

  A `datetime` has years, months and days as properties, if you want them in `str` format you could:

  `map(str, iterable)` to convert them into strings

## Code

```
import datetime
import os.path

now = datetime.datetime.now()
y, m = map(str, (now.year, now.month))

location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ipath = os.path.join(location, 'images', y, m + '.jpeg')
video_path_mp4 = os.path.join(location, 'videos', y, m + '.mp4')
video_path_webm = os.path.join(location, 'videos', y, m + '.webm')
```